# Русские словари

Tags: лексикография, значение-слов

Расскажите пожалуйста, ребята: почему есть так много словарей на русском языке? Почему те, кто организуют эти словари, не просто решили совместить все в одной версии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы предлагаете совместить содержимое словарей разных лет, то результат этого попросту не будет отражать современного состояния русского языка. Даже сами словарные статьи с толкованием слов окажутся написанными в стиле разных авторов и в духе разных эпох. Например, словарь Даля - в некотором роде литературный памятник своей эпохи, это большой индивидуальный труд и его было бы странно в чём-либо "растворять". При такой попытке сведения к единому значимость некоторых слов по частоте употребления окажется преувеличенной, смысл многих слов - устаревшим. Кроме этого, разные авторы-современники по-своему понимают и излагают некоторые особенности слов, в соответствии с личным опытом исследований и языковыми предпочтениями (кто-то - хороший исследователь этимологии и т.п., а кто-то - хороший литератор и толкователь). Поэтому (напр.) толковый словарь - в значительной мере авторский труд, хотя можно себе представить и компиляции со ссылкой на оригинальных авторов. Тем не менее, при желании сейчас несложно совместить разные словари в электронной форме, с той разницей, что присутствовать будут все альтернативные варианты статей (например, это можно сделать в словарях типа Lingvo - подключением всех, либо избранных словарей).